# Puppet - Not able to find a declared class

Tags: vagrant, puppet

Im trying to use classes in puppet. I have the following setup:

- manifest/

  - default.pp
  - web.pp

I tried to call the class web in my default.pp:

```
class { 'web': }
```

I've got the following error:

```
"Error: Could not find class web for ubuntu-14.localdomain on node ubuntu-14.localdomain"
```

What am I doing wrong?

The class is declared in web.pp as follows:

```
class web {
   package {'apache2':
          ensure => 'installed',
  }
}
```

I also tried to call the class as: include web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably move the web class as a new module

```
puppet
├── _manifest
|   └── default.pp
├── _modules
|   ├── _web
|   |   └── _manifests
|   |       └── init.pp
```

Just rename your file `web.pp` as `web/manifest/init.pp`

In the `default.pp` make sure to include your module:

```
class { 'web': }
include web
```

PS: make sure to reference your module directory from the vagrant provisioning